# android ndk native executable (not app) write permission

Tags: android, c++, unix, android-ndk, nexus-4

i have a rooted android phone, on which i run native c executables through the adb shell.
I am not using neither Java nor the Java NDK-apps, since i want to do low-level work with this app and no form of interaction with the user.
While everything runs fine, when i try to write a file (i.e. using std::ofstream of fprintf etc), the file is created but it is empty.

For Apps development i know you need to add a line in the Manifest.XML, so that you have write permissions.

Any suggestions for the native executable?

Comment: If the file is located on the rootfs or one of the other system partitions, then you must remount the fs as read/write.

Other than that, try issuing a sync programaticaly or via adb.

Comment: I understand the remounting, but what do you mean by issuing a sync?

Comment: For example if i type echo "test" > test.txt on adb i can write to the file. For some reason the c program though does not write.

Comment: sync() forces a write.  Android will typically cache writes otherwise.

Comment: I tried both the mounting and flushing the file. None of the worked. It has to do with the android permissions probably.

Comment: Does the write() return an error?  What is the access mask on the directory?

Comment: OK, when i compile the file as .c (so it compiles using gcc) it is fine, it writes. ok. Now the exact same code (if i put it in a cpp file), so it compiles using g++ it runs but does not write to the file. The code follows 
`#include <string.h>
#include <jni.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {

FILE* file = fopen("/sdcard/hello.txt","w+");

    if (file != NULL)
    {
     printf("Writing...\n");
        fputs("HELLO WORLD!\n", file);
        fflush(file);
        fclose(file);
    }
    return 0;
}`

Comment: Also the if statement, when i compile with C, passes (file != NULL), but when i compile with CPP it does not! (file == NULL). I got the same when i test the good() property of an ofstream for the cpp case.

Comment: OK, a little more info. Printing the errno, i get "Too many open files" Now this does not happen if i compile with C instead of CPP